# Java Error: String cannot be resolved into a type(S is uppercase)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

In this code I get the error (from eclipse) "String cannot be resolved into a type":

```
package tilegame.display;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Display {
        private JFrame frame;
        private String title;
        private int width, height;
        public Display() {
            public Display(String title, int width, int height){
                this.title = title;
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                createDisplay();
            }
        }
        public void createDisplay() {
            frame = new JFrame(title);
            frame.setSize(width, height);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        }
```

I searched But "String" is upercase and I have the Java Library from Eclipse.

Comment: Why do you have one constructor inside another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not nest the constructors. Try this:

```
package tilegame.display;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display {
    private JFrame frame;
    private String title;
    private int width, height;
    public Display() {

    }
    public Display(String title, int width, int height){
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        createDisplay();
    }
    public void createDisplay() {
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```